# Filter rows based on a keyword present in 1 field of complex JSON in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

A complex JSON file looks like below.

```
{"Activename": "ZenerDiode", "composition": " BACKWARDS\n3 Zener voltages and some\n1 Zener voltages and some\n2 sounds  electronic circuits gradual junction (silicon)\n  Zener effect\n1 supply rails, Diced\n3 higher voltage and to provide, reference\n4 Paste\n4 electronic circuits Stock Or Broth, More If Needed For Thinning\n Several Dashes Worcestershire\n1/2 teaspoon Sugar\n4 whole Carrots, Peeled And Diced\n2 whole Turnips, Peeled And Diced\n2 Tablespoons Minced Fresh Parsley\n Mashed Potatoes\n5 pounds Russet Potatoes (peeled)\n1 package (8 Ounce) Cream Cheese, Softened\n1 stick Butter, Softened\n1/2 cup Heavy Cream\n1 teaspoon Seasoned Salt\n Salt And Pepper, to taste", "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_diode", "image": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_diode.jpg", "reverseTime": "PT3H", "Yield": "8", "datePublished": "2013-01-14", "upTime": "PT15M", "description": "Yesterday was cold and windy and shivery and frigid, and to psychologically withstand such things, I made Sunday Night Stew a..."}
{"Activename": "Coil Capacitor", "composition": "2 Tablespoons Butter\n2 whole Large Onions, Halved And Sliced Thin\n1/4 cup Broth\n7 dashes Worcestershire Sauce\n Splash Of Red Or White Wine\n1/2 cup Grated Gruyere Cheese (can Use Swiss)\n Kosher Salt\n24 whole White Or Crimini Mushrooms, Washed And Stems Removed\n Minced Parsley", "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_diode", "image": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_diodejpg", "reverseTime": "PT30M", "Yield": "8", "datePublished": "2010-11-23", "upTime": "PT20M", "description": "Important note: this recipe has absolutely nothing to do with Thanksgiving.     I'm so glad I got that out. I feel cleansed! ..."}
{"Activename": "Metal Inductor", "composition": " STEW\n3 Tablespoons Olive Oil\n1 Tablespoon Butter\n2 pounds  electronic circuits Stew Meat (chuck Roast Cut Into Chunks)\n Salt And Pepper\n1 whole Medium Onion, Diced\n3 cloves Garlic, Minced\n4 ounces, weight Tomato Paste\n4 cups Low electronic circuits Stock Or Broth, More If Needed For Thinning\n Several Dashes Worcestershire\n1/2 teaspoon Sugar\n4 whole Carrots, Peeled And Diced\n2 whole Turnips, Peeled And Diced\n2 Tablespoons Minced Fresh Parsley\n Mashed Potatoes\n5 pounds Russet Potatoes (peeled)\n1 package (8 Ounce) Cream Cheese, Softened\n1 stick Butter, Softened\n1/2 cup Heavy Cream\n1 teaspoon Seasoned Salt\n Salt And Pepper, to taste", "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_diode", "image": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_diode.jpg", "reverseTime": "PT3H", "Yield": "8", "datePublished": "2013-01-14", "upTime": "PT15M", "description": "Yesterday was cold and windy and shivery and frigid, and to psychologically withstand such things, I made Sunday Night Stew a..."}
```

i have created a Dataframe out of it.

when i tried to filter only those rows from dataframe whose composition contain **electronic circuits** like

```
ds = df_concat.filter(lower("composition").like("%electronic circuits%"))
```

but it is not giving any records.

Please suggest.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your sample data , I can see the records are getting filtered

## Data Preparation

```
js = [
    {"Activename": "ZenerDiode", "composition": " BACKWARDS\n3 Zener voltages and some\n1 Zener voltages and some\n2 sounds  electronic circuits gradual junction (silicon)\n  Zener effect\n1 supply rails, Diced\n3 higher voltage and to provide, reference\n4 Paste\n4 electronic circuits Stock Or Broth, More If Needed For Thinning\n Several Dashes Worcestershire\n1/2 teaspoon Sugar\n4 whole Carrots, Peeled And Diced\n2 whole Turnips, Peeled And Diced\n2 Tablespoons Minced Fresh Parsley\n Mashed Potatoes\n5 pounds Russet Potatoes (peeled)\n1 package (8 Ounce) Cream Cheese, Softened\n1 stick Butter, Softened\n1/2 cup Heavy Cream\n1 teaspoon Seasoned Salt\n Salt And Pepper, to taste", "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_diode", "image": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_diode.jpg", "reverseTime": "PT3H", "Yield": "8", "datePublished": "2013-01-14", "upTime": "PT15M", "description": "Yesterday was cold and windy and shivery and frigid, and to psychologically withstand such things, I made Sunday Night Stew a..."}
    ,{"Activename": "Coil Capacitor", "composition": "2 Tablespoons Butter\n2 whole Large Onions, Halved And Sliced Thin\n1/4 cup Broth\n7 dashes Worcestershire Sauce\n Splash Of Red Or White Wine\n1/2 cup Grated Gruyere Cheese (can Use Swiss)\n Kosher Salt\n24 whole White Or Crimini Mushrooms, Washed And Stems Removed\n Minced Parsley", "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_diode", "image": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_diodejpg", "reverseTime": "PT30M", "Yield": "8", "datePublished": "2010-11-23", "upTime": "PT20M", "description": "Important note: this recipe has absolutely nothing to do with Thanksgiving.     I'm so glad I got that out. I feel cleansed! ..."}
    ,{"Activename": "Metal Inductor", "composition": " STEW\n3 Tablespoons Olive Oil\n1 Tablespoon Butter\n2 pounds  electronic circuits Stew Meat (chuck Roast Cut Into Chunks)\n Salt And Pepper\n1 whole Medium Onion, Diced\n3 cloves Garlic, Minced\n4 ounces, weight Tomato Paste\n4 cups Low electronic circuits Stock Or Broth, More If Needed For Thinning\n Several Dashes Worcestershire\n1/2 teaspoon Sugar\n4 whole Carrots, Peeled And Diced\n2 whole Turnips, Peeled And Diced\n2 Tablespoons Minced Fresh Parsley\n Mashed Potatoes\n5 pounds Russet Potatoes (peeled)\n1 package (8 Ounce) Cream Cheese, Softened\n1 stick Butter, Softened\n1/2 cup Heavy Cream\n1 teaspoon Seasoned Salt\n Salt And Pepper, to taste", "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_diode", "image": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_diode.jpg", "reverseTime": "PT3H", "Yield": "8", "datePublished": "2013-01-14", "upTime": "PT15M", "description": "Yesterday was cold and windy and shivery and frigid, and to psychologically withstand such things, I made Sunday Night Stew a..."}
]

jsonRDD = sc.parallelize(js)

sparkDF = sql.read.json(jsonRDD)

sparkDF.show()

+--------------+-----+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------+------+--------------------+
|    Activename|Yield|         composition|datePublished|         description|               image|reverseTime|upTime|                 url|
+--------------+-----+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------+------+--------------------+
|    ZenerDiode|    8| BACKWARDS
3 Zene...|   2013-01-14|Yesterday was col...|https://en.wikipe...|       PT3H| PT15M|https://en.wikipe...|
|Coil Capacitor|    8|2 Tablespoons But...|   2010-11-23|Important note: t...|https://en.wikipe...|      PT30M| PT20M|https://en.wikipe...|
|Metal Inductor|    8| STEW
3 Tablespoo...|   2013-01-14|Yesterday was col...|https://en.wikipe...|       PT3H| PT15M|https://en.wikipe...|
+--------------+-----+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------+------+--------------------+
```

## Filter

```
sparkDF.filter(F.col('composition').like('%electronic circuits%')).show()

+--------------+-----+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------+------+--------------------+
|    Activename|Yield|         composition|datePublished|         description|               image|reverseTime|upTime|                 url|
+--------------+-----+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------+------+--------------------+
|    ZenerDiode|    8| BACKWARDS
3 Zene...|   2013-01-14|Yesterday was col...|https://en.wikipe...|       PT3H| PT15M|https://en.wikipe...|
|Metal Inductor|    8| STEW
3 Tablespoo...|   2013-01-14|Yesterday was col...|https://en.wikipe...|       PT3H| PT15M|https://en.wikipe...|
+--------------+-----+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------+------+--------------------+
```

Comment: i am getting error as Cannot find reference 'col' in 'functions.py' . i have used from pyspark.sql.functions import lower, col but it is throwing error as Cannot find reference 'lower' in 'functions.py' . please help

Comment: Your import statement seems to be correct , 
Just for safety try - `import pyspark.sql.functions as F`

and use as `F.lower` and `F.col` respectively

Comment: df_concat.filter(F.lower("composition").like("%electronic circuits%")).show()....... but no luck... is it correct ?

Comment: May i request you to have 1-1 chat, if possible please